# Nginx does not get updated IP from AWS load balancer

Tags: nginx, nginx-config

I have following configuration in nginx to proxy a call to AWS internal load balancer. This configuration works until I think AWS changes the IP of the load balancer. I feel nginx does not get updated IP to make the call go through once ELB IP changes. I see timeout errors in the error.log (see below for an example log). Once I `reload` nginx it will start working. Can you tell me what should I do in nginx so updated IP at AWS Load balancer will be picked up by nginx and further call can be made to new IP?

```
      location /cx/ {
        resolver 69.254.169.253 10.4.0.2 valid=5s ipv6=off;
        resolver_timeout 15s;
        set $feupstream http://aws-internal-app-load-balancer-url:8092;
        
        set $ischeckout true;
        proxy_set_header X-CHECKOUT $ischeckout;
        proxy_pass_request_headers on;
        proxy_pass $feupstream;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_buffer_size 64k;
        proxy_buffers 4 64k;
        proxy_busy_buffers_size 64k;
        proxy_hide_header X-Powered-By;
        
    }
```

Error log in nginx `error.log`

```
[error] 22060#0: *647056 connect() failed (113: No route to host) while connecting to upstream, client:.....
[error] 22060#0: *188038 upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) while connecting to upstream, client:
```